# github local wiki (aka gollum), how to use static files?

Tags: git, github, gollum-wiki

I've done my research and I cannot find a solution to this problem. Can the  Gollum HTTP server serve static files? I'm trying to do that from the local copy of my project's wiki, cloned from gitHub, and of course I've installed Gollum on my PC.

I've tried to create a .png image and a PDF, I put them on the wiki's root, on images/ and docs/ directories, I've tried to commit them onto the repo (without pushing to github). Nothing worked, Gollum lists only wiki pages in 'All Files' and there's no URL that can point at such files (when I try things like `http://localhost:4567/test.png` it shows the form to create a new page).

I've read documentation that shows how to link images located on the main project repository (not inside the wiki folder), which seems to be like any external URL, but that's not what I want, cause my documentation is going to contain large PDF files and alike, which are not needed by developers, while they work on the code.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all committed files by launching gollum with the `--show-all` flag.

Comment: For the record here's the [unresolved issue](https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/809) you are having with this flag.

Comment: I've sent this same question as a Gollum bug and --show-all doesn't seem to work.